# maven executing profile independent of phase

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a profile which I want to execute after install phase is complete for all the modules.
say I have

```
<modules>
    <a>
    <b>
    <c>
</modules>
```

Then I have defined a profile whose id is `generate-reports`.

```
<profile>
    <id>generate-reports</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>run-cmd</id>
                    <!--DO NOT BIND WITH PHASE-->
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>executable-name</executable>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>-o</argument>
                    <argument>output.txt</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

This profile is a report generate profile which will go inside each module and generate report there. but problem is if I want to generate report once the test cases for each reports are run. this profile should not be invoked for each module while installation. Only after complete installation it should be invoked.
In other words I am looking for something like
      `mvn install generate-reports`
or even
      'mvn generate-reports' (assuming I already run `mvn install` individually).
In all I do not want to bind profile with phase and want to run profile independent of phase.

Is there any plugin to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can start any goal just by calling the goals name, e.g.:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

in your case, this should be:

```
mvn exec:exec
```

And as described [>here<](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) you can also do this:

```
mvn clean install exec:exec
```

This should finish a full "install" before invoking your report plugin.